# Hiding base class dependency property in derived control

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I am writing a set of custom TextBox controls for different data types. I do not only want the text to be validated (which I do) but also store the input in a property of adequate type.

So for example I have an UnsignedIntegerBox which inherits from TextBox, should store the input in an "uint UnsignedInteger" property, whith default set in xaml. It validates the input in the OnPreviewTextInput event. The OnTextChanged is used to update the UnsignedInteger from Text.

**Question:** Is there any way to hide the TextBox.Text property so that it is not exposed (and cannot be used) in XAML ?

Comment: Trying to hide the Text property seems awkward and is probably not a good approach. You may want to consider basing your custom control on a lower level object, e.g the `System.Windows.Controls.Control` class. This is how the framework implemented the '[PasswordBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.passwordbox?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)' class, which has no Text property.

Comment: Thanks, so I understand that by "awkward" you rather mean "impossible", or just "not recommended, but possible" ? In case of the latter I would be interested for the records in how this could be achieved, and why it is not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to create new CustomTextbox class that could inherit from UserControl / Control  class, create a DP property on it as you want and bind it to a TextBox in Control template / Content of your new control. So that you still use TextBox for input/visuals  but from code point it is hidden behind your new CustomTextBox class

Comment: Ok, but the major drawback is that I have to redefine (remap) any DP from the original TextBox to my custom control instead of only hiding one.

From your suggestion there are two paths as far as I see (I am quite new to C# / WPF, digging since a few weeks only). One would be the straight forward UserControl. The other would be a CustomControl  with a TextBox in the control template defined in generic.xaml (theme). Correct ? Is there any advantage of using the CustomControl (less straight forward) approach over the UserControl ?

Comment: You don't need to redefine / map all DP properties, some properties like FontSize, Foreground, FontFamily are inherited implicitly from parent. UserControl are easier to create but harder to create speacial themes (change their appearance later), when inheriting from other more low level classes like Control / ContentControl, you usually define their appearence (ControlTemplate / Style) in different file (CustomResourceDictionary.xaml / generic,xaml), but they appearance can be anytime change by anyone very easily. I would use TextBox in both UserControl and Control/ContentControl.

Comment: If you don't plan your textbox have multiple themes you can just use UserControl, If you do plan to change it's visuals drastically (not just font size or border), use Control class. I recently created LatitudePicker (basically just textBox with custom DP property instead of Text DP). I used UserControl and inside I used TextBox which uses the application TextBox visuals since i want to LatitudePicker look like any normal textBox but I don't want to expose all TextBox properties etc. If anything changes TextBox visuals in application, even my LatitucePicker will change.

Comment: Of course I know that I don't have to redefine/map any DP from the parent class, I was only referring to those defined by TextBox and "lost" by using an ancestor of it as base class.

But thanks for your comments anyway as they confirm my view and thus are very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

When you extend a superclass, then the subclass *is* the superclass. You can never remove any members of the superclass. You can change the behavior by overriding virtual members or hiding accessible members. Maybe you should revisit the inheritance rules of OO languages like C# to understand the concept.

This is what you can do, where 3, 4, 5 are the only clean and useful solutions:

1. When you hide the `Text` property to declare it `private`, then you would get a XAML error, due to the type inference of the XAML engine. This way the Text property is available via Intellisense, but you can't set it. But in C# the next accessible member is chosen. The member lookup behavior will automatically exclude the new hiding private `Text` property and will then find the `public` superclass member.

```cs
class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
  // Only has an effect in XAML
  new private string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Even if this would work, you could always set the static `DependencyProperty` using the `DependencyObject.SetValue` method. Hiding is also only *hiding* and not removing. You can always cast to the superclass to get access to the original `Text` property.

2. You can override the `DependencyProperty` meta data to disallow data binding

```cs
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
  static MyTextBox()
  {
    TextBox.TextProperty.OverrideMetadata(
      typeof(MyTextBox), 
      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.NotDataBindable));
  }
}
```

This will throw an exception if you try to *bind* to the `Text` property.
But you can still set the value via assignment.

3. Use composition over inheritance. You can the design the class API to your requirements and delegate the functionality to the inaccessible composition type.

```cs
// Alternatively extend Control
class MyTextBox : TextBoxBase
{
  private TextBox TextBox { get; }

  public int Number
  { 
     get => return this.TextBox.Text;
     set
     {
       if ( IsValid(value))
       {
         this.TextBox.Text = value;
       }
     }
}
```

4. Extend the class in the type hierarchy that does not declare the unwanted members. In your case this would be `TextBoxBase`.

```cs
// Will not have a Text property
class MyTextBox : TextBoxBase
{
}
```

5. Throw a `NotSupportedException` exception to make using the inherited members impossible. The developer is immediately notified that e.g., the `Text` property is not availble. May not be the best solution for public libraries.

```cs
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
  static MyTextBox()
  {
    TextBox.TextProperty.OverrideMetadata(
      typeof(MyTextBoxl), 
      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, OnCoerceText));
  }

  private static object OnCoerceText(DependencyObject d, object baseValue) 
    => throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your extended suggestions. I am programming OO since nearly 30 years, mostly in C++, so there is no issue with OO concept understanding. My question was purely C# and  more precisely WPF. I was never speaking of "removing" but "hiding" it for WPF. Especially since I was using Text internally anyway. I hoped there was some metadata trick to achieve this, but obviously there is none.

1&2 are clear and not advisable

Comment: 3. I think here you did not want to inherit from TextBox but Control or TextBoxBase ;-)  Also I do not see how composition could help as it would split what XamlSees and interacts with and it seems to be very hard to figure out (for any control in general) which interactions need to be linked and how between external and internal control for its mechanics to work as expected. The correct composition IMHO would be UserControl

Comment: 4. Similar was already suggested and my queestion was if this includes setting the control template in generic.xaml to work correctly ? Because just subclassing Control or even TextBoxBase does also remove the additional TextBox mechanics for editing the Text which needs then to be be implemented (i.e. duplicated) in the new control.

 5. Does not work in my initial scenario as I would still use Text internally

Comment: 3) Yes, it's a copy&paste left over from 2). Thanks, I have fixed it. Composition helps, because it allows you to hide fuctionality. The TextBox functionality is now private to composed class. If you extend TextBoxBase, then you get the majority of features that make a TextBox. The rest is delegated to the private TextBox. Like in the example , you replace the Text property with a Number property. When you delegate this value to the private TextBox, you get all the functionality that usually take place when setting the Text property. Except it is now hidden from the public.

Comment: In other words, you use the existing TextBox.Text implementation for your Number property. I can elaborate this example if you want me to. In this context the correct composition would never be UserControl. It will give you nothing and you would have to implement the complete TextBox functionality yourself. 4) Of course you would have to provide a new default Style as the subclass is no longer a TextBox. Therefore all the functionality that comes with TextBox and does not exist in TextBoxBase is lost. If you want to use the Text property internally, then solution 3) is yours.

Comment: 2) Is generally a good and valid solution if you want to disallow binding to the property. It's just not useful in your case. 1) is definitely not advisable, I agree with you.

Comment: From what you told me so far, I would recommend to use composition to solve your problem. Or, reconsider to use Text in the first place. I've done various numeric or other special feature TextBox implementations. It never occured to me that the Text property is problematic in any way. What ever makes you believe that you need to hide it maybe solved in a smarter way. Maybe you like to share your thoughts why you believe the Text property must be hidden?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your repeat extensive reply. Thanks also for th eoffer to even elaborate more, but I don't want to use more of your time than required :-)  I will now invest some time in figuring out how to proceed and may come back to you.

Using composition wanting to simulate class X child of class Y, by inheriting class Y and composing with class X has a general problem of split functionality which could be easily manageable in local classes  but bear risks in public library classes, So far to the generic OO theory, I will now give the WPF classes a try and see...

Comment: Just the promised update:  I  finally dropped the composition path due to the OO split brain dilema and the required investment of time. I started to write a VS extension for refactoring code for automatic control composition but finally paused it as the required investment of time outtakes the benefits.

Comment: I did want to hide the Text property (and others like MinLength/MaxLength) mainly for data normalization removing duplicate field which may both be set but overwriting each other and other side-effects like setting MaxValue to 1000 and MaxLength to 3 which would never allow 1000, etc...

Comment: I see. I still believe that there is no reason to hide those properties. They only provide convenience as you can use it the way you expect a TextBox to be used. You can always add your own property changed handlers and coerce callbacks by overriding the meta data of the e.g., Text property. Using a coerce callback for example allows you to validate the e.g., MaxLength value to prevent that it conflicts with your new logic. This way you can change the behavior - the coerce callback is called before the property is actually set.

Comment: This is a far more better solution than to introduce new properties to shadow existing behavior. Also it doesn't change the API of the control too much. If it is a TextBox it must "behave" or appear as one.